# Use Count in Linq returns different results than SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linqer

I use Linqer to convert SQL to LinQ but result are not the same
My SQL query :

```
    Select ChuyenNganh.ChuyenNganhID,ChuyenNganh.TenChuyenNganh,SoLuong= count(BaiBao.ChuyenNganhID )
from BaiBao right join ChuyenNganh on ChuyenNganh.ChuyenNganhID = BaiBao.ChuyenNganhID
group by  ChuyenNganh.ChuyenNganhID, ChuyenNganh.TenChuyenNganh
```

Convert to Linq

```
var queryChuyenNganh = from t in myPhanLoaiTaiLieuDataContext.ChuyenNganhs
                                   join t0 in myPhanLoaiTaiLieuDataContext.BaiBaos on new { ChuyenNganhID = t.ChuyenNganhID } equals new { ChuyenNganhID = Convert.ToInt32(t0.ChuyenNganhID) } into t0_join
                                   from t0 in t0_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   group t by new
                                   {
                                       t.ChuyenNganhID,
                                       t.TenChuyenNganh
                                   } into g
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       ChuyenNganhID = (System.Int32)g.Key.ChuyenNganhID,
                                       g.Key.TenChuyenNganh,

                                       SoLuong  =(Int32)g.Count()
                                   };
```

Result:

**Linq**

[image]

**SQL**

[image]

Who can fix it for me?

Comment: The `t0_join.DefaultIfEmpty()` will be returning an default value for the 0 count rows hence the 1

Comment: I think in your sql query you doing right join BaiBao with ChuyenNganh and In you Linq you doing right join ChuyenNganh with BaiBao. Order matter for right or left join and you are counting base count(BaiBao.ChuyenNganhID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the SQL query can be rewritten in LINQ without `group by` but simple LINQ `GroupJoin`.

But the main issue with your conversion is that SQL `COUNT(expr)` does not count `NULL` values, and there is no direct LINQ equivalent, so either conditional `Count` or `Sum` is needed (I personally prefer the later because usually it translates to better SQL).

So, the minimum change needed in you query is

`group t by new` to `group t0 by new`

and `SoLuong =(Int32)g.Count()` to `SoLuong = g.Sum(t0 => t0 != null ? 1 : 0)`

P.S. As mentioned at the beginning, I would give a try to the following LINQ query:

```
var queryChuyenNganh = 
    from t in myPhanLoaiTaiLieuDataContext.ChuyenNganhs
    join bb in myPhanLoaiTaiLieuDataContext.BaiBaos
    on t.ChuyenNganhID equals bb.ChuyenNganhID into t_BaiBaos
    select new
    {
        t.ChuyenNganhID,
        t.TenChuyenNganh,
        SoLuong = t_BaiBaos.Count()
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that SQL counts non-null values in `BaiBao.ChuyenNganhID`, a column in the outer join table, while LINQ counts all records.

You need to make LINQ count non-null values as well:

```
var queryChuyenNganh = from t in myPhanLoaiTaiLieuDataContext.ChuyenNganhs
   join t0 in myPhanLoaiTaiLieuDataContext.BaiBaos
       on new { t.ChuyenNganhID } equals new { ChuyenNganhID = Convert.ToInt32(t0.ChuyenNganhID) } into t0_join
   from t0 in t0_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
   group new {T=t, NonNull=t0.ChuyenNganhID != null} by new
   {
       t.T.ChuyenNganhID,
       t.T.TenChuyenNganh
   } into g
   select new
   {
       ChuyenNganhID = (System.Int32)g.Key.ChuyenNganhID,
       g.Key.TenChuyenNganh,
       SoLuong  =(Int32)g.Count(x => x.NonNull)
   };
```

Comment: i don't think so. after group by t in to g, g not contain BaiBao.ChuyenNganhID so g have not  non-null values

Comment: @DiênCông Did you read and understand the query in the answer?